# How does Prometheus scrape multiple node server behind load balancer

Tags: node.js, prometheus

I have one question regarding nodeJS as prometheus metrics end point.

When I am using php prometheus client, I can pass redisStore into the registry, so even if I have multiple php client after load balancer, if prometheus scrape the load balancer, all the php clients will give the same metrics.

But now I want to use nodeJS, but when I look at pom-client library, I can not find out any trace as the shared store for the registry. If this is the case, how can the prometheus scape the load balancer to get the metrics?

I think the Load Balancer will forward the /metrics call to any of the end  nodeJS points, how come each nodeJS point give same output for the metrics if they do not have shared store as registry?